# PostgreSQL non-overlapping ranges

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL database and have a `cards` table.

Each record(card) in this table have `card_drop_rate` integer value.

For example:

```
id | card_name |card_drop_rate
-------------------------------
1  |card1      |34
2  |card2      |16
3  |card3      |54
```

max drop rate is `34 + 16 + 54 = 104`.

In accordance to my application logic I need to find a random value between 0 and 104 and then retrieve card according to this number, for example:

random value: `71`

```
card1 range: 0 - 34(0 + 34)
card2 range: 34 - 50(34 + 16)
card3 range: 50 - 104(50 + 54)
```

So, my card is card3 because `71` is placed in the range `50 - 104`

What is the proper way to reflect this structure in PostgreSQL ? I'll need to query this data often under so the performance is a criterion number one for this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query works fine:

```
SELECT
b.id,
b.card_drop_rate
FROM (SELECT a.id, sum(a.card_drop_rate) OVER(ORDER BY id) - a.card_drop_rate as rate, card_drop_rate FROM cards as a) b
WHERE b.rate < 299 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using cumulative sums and random.  The "+ 1"s might be throwing me off, but it is something like this:

```
with c as (
      select c.*,
             sum(card_drop_rate + 1) - card_drop_rate as threshhold
      from cards c
     ),
     r as (
      select random() * (sum(card_drop_rate) + count(*) - 1) as which_card
      from cards c
     )
select c.*
from c cross join
     r
where which_card >= threshhold
order by threshhold
limit 1;
```

For performance, I would simply take the cards and generate a new table with 106 slots.  Assign the card value to the slots and build an index on the slot number.  Then get a value using:

```
select s.*
from slots s
where s.slotid = floor(random() * 107);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately I can't execute the first query because of some syntax error there..

Comment: and yes, +1 can be avoided there